# Import PFX under Admin-User works, but under Non-Admin-User it won't. Why?

Tags: powershell, import, certificate, pfx

Environment: Windows 10 Enterprise 2016 LTSB (Version: 1607; Build: 14393.2879)

every year we change certificates with a script. The pfx files + pwd will be delivered.

The script runs in the user-context.

The certs from last year run's manually under admin and non-admin user with the delivered password.

Problem:
The NEW certs only works automated under admin user or manually under non-admin user. But Why?

The certs options from old to new are the same if I check the properties after imported.

How can I get the problem solved?

greetz

```
$SecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $PWD -AsPlainText -Force
Get-ChildItem -Path $Path | Import-PfxCertificate -CertStoreLocation Cert:\CurrentUser\My -Password $SecurePassword
```

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly the problem is? if the certs from both years run correctly when manually run admin/non admin, what is the issue?

Comment: The issue is that the import of the old certs runs automated with both user type(admin, non-admin). With the new certs it just work with admin user. The script is the same, I just changed the certs + pwds.

Comment: Can we see the error message generated when you run the statements in an un-elevated session? The `Import-PfxCertificate` statement should be fine. The only problem I could see is if the certificate file (what you have in `$Path`) is in a place a non-admin can't access. Without seeing the error, I'm just guessing.

Comment: The error is "certificate could not be added." (bad english translation ^^), but the hint with the place where non-admin can't access let me open up a light. =) I'm going to check.

Comment: @Adam That was the problem. DIR permissions have been changed ;( *argh*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error reported as...

> certificate could not be added.

The Import-PfxCertificate statement should be fine because you can always import certificates to your own user store (cert:\CurrentUser\My). The only problem I could see is if the certificate file (what you have in $Path) is in a place a non-admin can't access.

Comment: Changed (by another admin) DIR Permissions. ;(